# Database Query by Keywords

Tags: mysql, database

I have following tables:

products_match:

```
atcode  varchar(6)
valcode varchar(100)
id_prod varchar(15)
```

products:

```
asin varchar(15)
title varchar(155)
```

Example content of products_match table:

```
atcode='type'
valcode='wifi'
id_prod='1SC52DD'

atcode='type'
valcode='ram'
id_prod='11DD5ER'
```

There are multiple kwywords in this table.

I'm budilding a simple search engine - I need to display products matching multiple criteria, example:
select products where atcode='type' AND valcode='wifi' AND valcode='brand' AND 'valcode' = 'Sony'

Do I need to apply self joins for every group of arguments here?

Right now I have following query:

```
SELECT * FROM products_match a
JOIN products b ON a.id_prod=b.asin
JOIN assortment_match c ON a.id_prod=c.id_prod
WHERE c.atcode='brand' AND c.valcode='sony'
ORDER BY sales_rank ASC LIMIT 0,60
```

however it returns no products.

Can anybody help me solve this issue?

**Edit**
I've been told that I should use one self join for every group of keywords. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

One method is that for each match, you could use an EXISTS subquery.

```
AND EXISTS (select 1 from products_match 
            where id_prod = a.id_prod
            and atcode = 'type' and valcode = 'wifi')
```

Comment: there might be a problem as whole query is generated in fly by PHP.

Comment: @John I'm not sure why.. it's common to generate queries on the fly and use this method.